# Error -104 creating Firebird stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird

I cannot run the following SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NYANSAT(
        FORNAVN VARCHAR(30),
        EFTERNAVN VARCHAR(30),
        ADRESSE VARCHAR(50),
        POSTNUMMER CHAR(4),
        TELEFONNUMMER CHAR(8),
        EMAIL VARCHAR(50))
    AS
    DECLARE VARIABLE ID INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      ID = GEN_ID(GEN_ANSAT_ID,1);
      INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, FORNAVN, EFTERNAVN, ADRESSE, POSTNUMMER, TELEFONNUMMER, EMAIL) VALUES (:ID, :FORNAVN, :EFTERNAVN, :ADRESSE, :POSTNUMMER, :TELEFONNUMMER, :EMAIL);
    END
```

The error I get is the following:

```
can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\Windows\firebird.msg not found.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 3, column 1.
CREATE.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you used Set Term before and after this code?

All commands in Firebird must be terminated with a semi-colon. If you want to create a stored procedure you need to be able to distinguish between the terminating semi-colon from the semi-colons inside the stored procedure.

Something like this:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NYANSAT(
        FORNAVN VARCHAR(30),
        EFTERNAVN VARCHAR(30),
        ADRESSE VARCHAR(50),
        POSTNUMMER CHAR(4),
        TELEFONNUMMER CHAR(8),
        EMAIL VARCHAR(50))
    AS
    DECLARE VARIABLE ID INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      ID = GEN_ID(GEN_ANSAT_ID,1);
      INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, FORNAVN, EFTERNAVN, ADRESSE, POSTNUMMER, TELEFONNUMMER, EMAIL) VALUES (:ID, :FORNAVN, :EFTERNAVN, :ADRESSE, :POSTNUMMER, :TELEFONNUMMER, :EMAIL);
    END
    ^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Please notice how the declaration of the stored procedure is terminated with ^, thus ending the statement. After the declaration you also restore the terminating semi-colon.

On a side note, I would recommend to copy firebird.msg to the location the error you get tells you so you can see what is really happening.

**EDIT:**

If you wish you can check this [link](http://firebird.borlandforum.com/impboard/attach/0000125642/IBExpertFirebirdGuide.pdf). There you can find a lot of information regarding Firebird + IBExpress, including SET TERM (page 81).

**EDIT 2:**

Just tried at home with IBExperts + Firebird and I had no problem creating the stored procedure. My guess is you are trying to do one of the following things:

- You have opened an SQL editor and are trying to compile the code directly. That will not work because IBExperts thinks you are trying to run DSQL sentences. Stored procedures are created with PSQL sentences.
- You are trying to use the "New procedure" utility (check buttons in the upper right side of the main menu) and pasted the whole code into the editor. That will not work because in that editor you only have to put the body code. Stored procedure name is set in a field on the upper right side of the window you opened. Parameters and variables are introduced by using the "Insert Parameter/Variable" button on the left side above the code editor. The SET TERM sentences are created automatically by IBExperts. You can check the resulting code in the DDL tab.

HTH

Comment: With that I get the following error:                              Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 3, column 1.
SET.

Comment: Which tool are you using to create the SP? Is it isql or another one? SET TERM is specific to Firebird, as far as I know, so whatever component or tool you use to create the SP needs to be able to recognize it.

Comment: I copied the code exactly as it is.. I'm using IBExpert to create the procedures.. perhaps it is IBExpert that doesnt understand it?

Comment: I have IBExperts + Firebird at home. I will check it when I get there. Meanwhile, if you wish you could check the URL I will add now to my answer.

Comment: @Herter, just added some information on using IBExperts + Firebird. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi again.. I got it to work.. thank you for the help :)   I had to manually add the parameters and variables with the GUI and only paste the but between "begin" and "end" in.. so your post was very helpful :)